# Feature request: Closed at the beginning of the title

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, closed-questions, title

Feature request: [Closed] at the beginning of the title.

I click on a link only to find the question is closed, duplicate, .... I don't read right to left. [Closed] should be put at the beginning of the title.

Comment: "I don't read right to left" - that's not a problem at all if you read the entire title. Also note that if a question is closed while your cached version thinks it isn't, it won't update to say it's closed.

Comment: Search for closed:no then, you'll only see open questions.

Comment: @rob I will take that as an answer if you want to post it.

Comment: What links are you seeing and clicking on? Where are they located? What page? There's really no way to answer this without knowing exactly which links you're talking about.

Answer (score 7):

The *most* significant information should go on the left, which is where people begin reading English text. The *least* significant information should go on the right, where it is more easily ignored.

That a question has been closed is the *least* significant piece of information proffered in the title region, so it belongs on the right side of the title.

Answer (score 4):

Since your aim is not to see closed questions, simply search for `closed:no` as well as your existing tags or other search terms. That way you’ll only see open questions and you won’t need to read the titles at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what value to the site this feature brings compared to current "Close" at the end. Site already promotes important information (tags) to front for search engines - adding "closed" there may lead to confusion.

If your goal is to hide closed question then again I don't see it as a good feature. The site does want to show closed and duplicate questions to people who can act on them in some way - meaning to all authenticated users. Maybe the question is incorrectly closed and needs edit/reopen votes, or there is better duplicate or any other moderation action needed.

If your goal not to see duplicates there is already an existing feature for the majority of SO visitors - just sign out and duplicates will automatically redirect to the target question.

Answer (score -4):

If you don’t want to display the closed questions, perhaps type in `closed:no` and `duplicate:no`.